# String Expansion with Variables

Tags: string, powershell, expansion

I have a config file, that contains strings used within my scripts. The config file is read via a C# class using this Syntax:

```
$final = $PropMgr.GetValue($section, $property)
$final = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($final)
```

This returns the string from the config file. Afterwards the returned string gets expanded because it may contain objects that need expansion

Everything works fine but for one thing. One of my strings in the config file looks like this:

```
Found $($scripts.Length) scripts to execute in the config file
```

`$scripts` is array, so the expanded string should look like this:

```
Found 6 scripts to execute in the config file
```

But using my code avove I receive an exception:

> Exception calling "ExpandString" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

If I debug the script and execute this code in a commandline:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("Found $($scripts.Length) scripts to execute in the config file")
```

Everything is fine, but using the `$final` variable instead of the string itself, I receive the exception again.

What do I have to do to achieve what I was looking for?

Comment: Could you show us the config file? Seems like `$PropMgr.GetValue($section, $property)` doesn't return anything

Comment: Did you inspect the value/type of `$final`?

Comment: Yes I did. $final is definitely filled with the corrct string value. I checked that several times